# RTSP Digest Authentication

Tags: java, rtsp

I am trying to have a RTSP connection using Digest Authentication

I see a session timeout of 60 secs, after which the connection is getting lost from camera, and again I had to reconnect.

Setup Response: TSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 07:33:25 GMT
Server: RTSP Server
Session: 821859694;timeout=60
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1;ssrc=03D25B5B
x-retransmit: our-retransmit
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
x-transport-options: late-tolerance=1
x-dynamic-rate: 1; rtt=16

How can I remove this session timeout dependency from the SETUP connection?

I need to get this resolved. Any help is appreciated.

I am using OPTIONS,DESCRIBE,SETUP and PLAY

Answer (score 0):

The session timeout is server's property, as a client you cant remove its dependency.

By specifying the session timeout server expects heartbeat from the client within the specified timeout. Session timeouts can be handled by periodically sending,

1. RTCP packets or
2. RTSP message i.e. OPTIONS or GET_PARAMETER

at a frequency lesser than the session timeout.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722467/keeping-alive-rtsp-connection)

Comment: Thank you Pragnesh, will try it out and let u know :-)